# Class com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver not found (Python, jaydebeapi module)

Tags: python, jaydebeapi

I am trying to connect to teradata using `jaydebeapi`.

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',
                           'jdbc:teradata://serverIP/charset=UTF8,DBS_PORT=1025',
                           {'user': 'xxx', 'password': 'xxx'},
[r'path_to_teradata_jdbc_driver/tdgssconfig.jar',r'path_to_teradata_jdbc_driver/terajdbc4.jar'])
```

When I run this script ($python "Run SQL_Java.py") I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Run SQL_Java.py", line 60,
>   in 
>       [r'path_to_teradata_jdbc_driver/tdgssconfig.jar',r'path_to_teradata_jdbc_driver/terajdbc4.jar'])
>   File
>   "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/**init**.py",
>   line 381, in connect
>       jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)   File
>   "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/**init**.py",
>   line 190, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
>       jpype.JClass(jclassname)   File "/Users/i.otenko/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jclass.py",
>   line 55, in JClass
>       raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name) jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver not
>   found

Am I not specifying path to JDBC drivers correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant code:

```
import jaydebeapi

USERNAME="user01"
PASSWORD="password01"
URL_CONNECTION="jdbc:teradata://server01/"
jars=['E:\\jdbc\\tdgssconfig.jar','E:\\jdbc\\terajdbc4.jar']

conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver', URL_CONNECTION,[USERNAME,PASSWORD], jars)
```

p.s. likely problem in `[r'path_to_teradata_jdbc_driver/tdgssconfig.jar',r'path_to_teradata_jdbc_driver/terajdbc4.jar']`