# Trying to connect and delete rows from teradata using python

Tags: python, teradata

I am trying to connect and delete rows from teradata table using python ,I know that python has some module to do that like below , but in my current project I cannot install them using pip as it is not allowed .But I have the required jar for teradata : teradatajdbc4.jar , tdgssconfig.jar.Using this 2 jar how can I connect and delete  rows from there

`````
import pandas as pd````
`````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866309/class-com-teradata-jdbc-teradriver-not-found-python-jaydebeapi-module

Comment: btw - Note that `pandas` does not natively support Teradata. You would either need a Teradata Python module of some sort  (typically `teradatasqlalchemy`) or some generic interface module like `jaydebeapi` or `pyodbc` plus a corresponding Teradata driver (that would be installed outside of the Python environment).